# How do I add a class to every menu item automatically in a nav menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu, customization

I currently have this markup:

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => 'main-nav',
    'container'       => 'ul',
    'container_class'    => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'before'          => '<button class="btn btn-warning">',
    'after'           => '</button>',
    'menu_class'      => '',
    'menu_id'         => 'menu',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">%3$s</div>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);
wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

Here is an example of [my site](http://testing.justrightwebsitesandvideos.com/)

With the current structure in place above, it seems like the links work fine for chrome except for firefox and ie

In addition, bootstrap's  element calls for the href link inside of the

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `items_wrap` option; a wordpress menu consists of an `<ul>`-tag and you should not insert containers into these.

While you have specified an id for your menu, you should be able to use

```
#menu li{
...
}
```

to style your menu items (at least that's what I'm doing with mine).

btw, your site is offline.

### Adding a class to the menu items

The following regex allows you to add a class to each (each!) element of your nav, that possesses the `class` tag. Since this only affects the `li` tags, it works quite well. Replace your `wp_nav_menu` call with this code:

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu(array(
    'echo'=>0, // this is important
    'menu'=>'YOUR_MENU_SLUG',
    // your args here
));

$menu_item_class = 'YOUR_CLASS_NAME';
$menu = preg_replace('/class="([^"]*)"/', 'class="$1 '.$menu_item_class.'"', $menu);
print($menu);
```

If you feel lucky, you can enhance the regex by letting it match to `li` tags only, but the code above will definitely work.

Comment: I totally understand this method but I am trying to add a class to every menu item's a link automatically in the nav menu.

Comment: I added that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response paolo.  I appreciate your help.  I have tried your code and It does work but not necessarily the way I need it to...  I am going to brainstorm my options and get back to this thread asap.